# Get EMR cluster to kill its EC2 instances on termination

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3, amazon-emr

My question is simple, is there anyway to get an EMR cluster to automatically kill the instances (Master + slave(s)) on termination?
If yes can it be done with boto3 ?

Thank you.

Comment: This is the default behavior when you terminate a cluster. Are you seeing the ec2 instances stick around after you delete?

Comment: yes, they stay alive

Comment: I precise that I am manually terminating the cluster

Comment: I have never seen such behaviour in EMR

Comment: You have "KeepJobFlowAliveWhenNoSteps" and "TerminationProtected" parameters you can set while creating a new cluster. Check [link](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/emr.html#EMR.Client.run_job_flow)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @sakhti srinivas,  "KeepJobFlowAliveWhenNoSteps" and "TerminationProtected" parameters can indeed be set [link](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/emr.html#EMR.Client.run_job_flow)